# JS Always show UK timezone

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, clock

I'd like the timestamp on this div to always show UK time regardless of where you are in the world. Currently it will show based on the user/browser location even though i've added the below to ensure UK time is visible.

```
function showDateTime() {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("time");
  var event = new Date();
console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' }));
```

I've shared this with some friends in the US and the time is showing local to them rather than the UK/time.

https://jsfiddle.net/xgwsk2b3/

Comment: The value you're logging with `console.log` is indeed UK time, but in the fiddle you've linked, you're using entirely different code to write the local time to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

With Intl API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

https://jsfiddle.net/danailvidev/vmo6cyh2/1/

```
function showDateTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
      dateStyle: 'full',
      timeStyle: 'long',
    });
    console.log(formatter.format(date));
}
setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);


// "Thursday, 6 January 2022 at 12:00:24 GMT"
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but I can't remember if it caters for summertime

Answer (score -1):

UTC solves your problem:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=uk+utc+time
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

I live in Germany and UTC+1 is my timezone, for the UK you need UTC+0

Comment: Can you show how this solves the problem?

Comment: `const date = new Date(); date.toUTCString();` returns `'Thu, 06 Jan 2022 11:46:25 GMT'` which should be UK time, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: great [resource](https://toastui.medium.com/handling-time-zone-in-javascript-547e67aa842d)

Comment: Uhhh, it depends a bit - it's correct at this time of year, but in the Summer we switch to BST (GMT + 1)

Comment: Did not know that, BUT I may have found the bug in your fiddle: the `event` variable logs the UK time, yet later on you create a new `date` variable, which does not have the UK settings. So use the `event` date instance :)